# functions selection random variable in r

Tags: r

I am trying to Using sample selection function  to randomly select 10 integers from 1 to 100. by creating a vector y which satisfies the following conditions: if an selected integer is an even
number, then y returns ‘even’, otherwise y returns ‘odd’.
I tried out the following codes but I am not getting it.]

Any help on this?
Thanks

```
vec<-rnorm (100)
myf <- function(vec){ 
  y = 
   for (i in vec) { 

      if (i %% 2 == 0) k <- k + 1

  return(y) 
   }
}
myf(vec)
```

```
vec <-rnorm (100)
myf <- function(vec){ 
  y = 
   for (i in vec) { 

      if (i %% 2 == 0) k <- k + 1

  return(y) 
   }
}
myf(vec)
```

Comment: `rnorm(100)` will give you 100 non-integer values...

Comment: I think you can use a vectorised approach instead of for loop like this: (a) get your vector: `vec<- sample(1:100, 10)`, (b) run this `ifelse(vec %% 2 == 1, "odd", "even")` which you can save as a function if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both following approach are equivalent :

```r
set.seed(123)
# Straight forward
res0 <- sample(x = c("even", "odd"), size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.5, .5) )
res0
#>  [1] "odd"  "even" "odd"  "even" "even" "odd"  "even" "even" "even" "odd"

# as you said
spl <- sample(x = 1:100, size = 10, replace = TRUE )
res1 <- ifelse(spl%%2 == 0, "even", "odd")
res1
#>  [1] "even" "even" "even" "even" "odd"  "even" "odd"  "odd"  "odd"  "even"
```